# How to change the font family when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I'm making a education website and I want to add a "toggle OpenDyslexic font" button which will change the website's font to OpenDyslexic.

I already have this:

```
*{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
    /* font-family: 'opendyslexic' !important; */
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'opendyslexic';
    src: url('fonts/od.otf');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
} 

.od {
    font-family: 'opendyslexic' !important;
}
```

Again, just to make it clear: can I make a button that will toggle the font (from Noto Sans JP to OpenDyslexic, and vice versa)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle the `od` class on the body.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", e=>{
  document.body.classList.toggle("od");
});
```

```css
*{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
    /* font-family: 'opendyslexic' !important; */
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'opendyslexic';
    src: url('fonts/od.otf');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
} 

.od {
    font-family: 'opendyslexic' !important;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
<br/>
<button>Toggle Font</button>
```

Comment: Hmm.. The code snippet works properly but if I use it on the website the button does nothing.

Comment: @nfszcqmtqpcretfxnu Please provide a minimal, reproducible example so I can help.

Comment: Nevermind, I had to move `font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;` from `*` to something like `.default`. It works now, sorry to have bothered you.

Comment: @nfszcqmtqpcretfxnu Would you mind accepting my answer if it solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto the other answer, I'd recommend using the body selector to style the font not the star selector. It wouldn't work adding a body modifier class as the star selector has a higher specificity.